# Can we change the value of attribute css by js

Tags: javascript, css

Can we change the value of the attribute CSS **class** by javascript?

I mean, I had to create

```
<li class="Item">first</li>
```

Where CSS class I have attribute `height: 200; width: 200;`

And the question is anyhow can I change the value in **class** of `height` && `width` by using javascript?

Comment: Yes you should definitely be able to find this by just googling 'set css with vanilla javascript'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting DIV width and height in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10118172/setting-div-width-and-height-in-javascript) and [Set element width or height in Standards Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667651/set-element-width-or-height-in-standards-mode)

Comment: Why do you want to do this? That could impact which solution you go with (set inline style, add a different class, generate a class, set the size on the list it's self instead of each element, etc).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can directly access CSS properties in the stylesheet, and [support for this is improving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620393/is-it-possible-to-alter-a-css-stylesheet-using-javascript-not-the-style-of-an/6620400#6620400), and actually [looks pretty good today](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSRule) (scroll down to browser compatibility section).

This will, however, not be a straight-forward process since, with a large stylesheet, you'll either have to traverse the `cssRules` array to find the appropriate class (best approach) or hard code the index of the class you want (<del>probably</del> don't do that. It works in the example because there is only one class).

Alternately, I suppose, as a compromise approach you could create a separate 'dynamic styles' stylesheet with only a few rules that might be changed dynamically later on.

Access the document stylesheet and modify the class you want like so:

```js
setTimeout(function(){ // Timeout used only for before/after comparison
  var stylesheet = document.styleSheets[0];
  stylesheet.cssRules[0].style.width = '50px';
  console.log(stylesheet.cssRules[0]);
}, 750);
```

```css
.item {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #000;
  margin: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">

</div>
<div class="item">

</div>
<div class="item">

</div>
```

Comment: More info at w3 - https://www.w3.org/wiki/Dynamic_style_-_manipulating_CSS_with_JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

```
var els = document.querySelectorAll(className);
var index = 0, length = els.length;
for (var i = 0 ; index < length; index++) {
    els[index].style.width= "500px";
    els[index].style.height= "500px";
}
```

className just works like normal css selectors, so you can do like "li.Item" for example.

This will affect all the elements with the "Item" class.

Answer (score 0):

Use [element.style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style):

```
var element = document.getElementsByClassName('Item');
element.style.width = "100px";
```

just like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195303/set-css-property-in-javascript)

Or you can use [jquery](http://api.jquery.com/css/):

```
$(".Item").css("width", "100px");
```

Answer (score -1):

Your best approach would probably to use the jQuery framework and use its .css() method.

http://api.jquery.com/css/

```
$('.Item).css('width', '200px')
```

That should do it.

If you want to do it with vanilla javascript you could try the following:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("Item").style.width = "300px";
```

Comment: We can do that in clean javascript? because Installing the entire jquery library just for this thing is probably meaningless

Comment: You could use the .style() method of vanilla javascript. I haven't tried it with class just ID, yet though.

Comment: Same here it only changes style of currently matched elements, it does not change the css-class style